# Using CASE statement in MDX for data from different hierarchy level

Tags: case, mdx

I have the following hierarchy created:

[image]

I have written this particular query to get my result:

```
WITH MEMBER [Ecotassa] AS 
CASE 
   WHEN [Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember.MemberValue = '2011' THEN '9114646'
   WHEN [Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember.MemberValue = '2012' THEN '8787551.65'
   WHEN [Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember.MemberValue = '2013' THEN '8435651.26'
   WHEN [Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember.MemberValue = '2014' THEN '8917336.39'
   WHEN [Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember.MemberValue = '2015' THEN '9465533.37'
   ELSE  NULL
END

SELECT 
{ [Measures].[Dato], [Ecotassa] } ON COLUMNS,
{ ([Tempo].[Periodo].[Mese Anno].MEMBERS) } ON ROWS

FROM [AGRO]
WHERE ([TipoMisura].[Tipo Misura].&[1], [TipoAnno].[Tipo Anno].&[2],
[TipoPeriodo].[Tipo Periodo].&[2],
[Mercato].[Mercato].&[1],
[Aziende].[Descrizione Codice Azienda].&[100 - BASF]);
```

The result that I am getting is:

[image]

This is not my desired result, for Ecotassa, I need to get the result for that particular year. But I am getting **null**.

Where am I going wrong with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `[Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember` is equal to `All` in your script hence it is choosing `NULL` in the `CASE` statement. I'd also be tempted to use `[Tempo].[Periodo]` for year and also for date: rather than `[Tempo].[Anno]`:

I've also thrown `[Measures].[y]` into the select so we can see if it is working ok.

So try this:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[y] AS 
  EXISTS(
    [Tempo].[Periodo].[Anno].members,
    [Tempo].[Periodo].CurrentMember
  ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0).Member_Caption
MEMBER [Measures].[Ecotassa] AS 
  CASE 
     WHEN [Measures].[y] = '2011' THEN '9114646'
     WHEN [Measures].[y] = '2012' THEN '8787551.65'
     WHEN [Measures].[y] = '2013' THEN '8435651.26'
     WHEN [Measures].[y] = '2014' THEN '8917336.39'
     WHEN [Measures].[y] = '2015' THEN '9465533.37'
   ELSE  NULL
  END
SELECT 
{ 
   [Measures].[Dato]
  ,[Measures].[Ecotassa]
  ,[Measures].[y] 
 } ON COLUMNS,
[Tempo].[Periodo].[Mese Anno].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [AGRO]
WHERE (
   [TipoMisura].[Tipo Misura].&[1]
  ,[TipoAnno].[Tipo Anno].&[2]
  ,[TipoPeriodo].[Tipo Periodo].&[2]
  ,[Mercato].[Mercato].&[1]
  ,[Aziende].[Descrizione Codice Azienda].&[100 - BASF]
 );
```

---

**test script**

What does this return?

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[EcotassaTEST] AS 
  [Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember.MemberValue

SELECT 
{ [Measures].[Dato], [EcotassaTEST] } ON COLUMNS,
{ ([Tempo].[Periodo].[Mese Anno].MEMBERS) } ON ROWS

FROM [AGRO]
WHERE ([TipoMisura].[Tipo Misura].&[1], [TipoAnno].[Tipo Anno].&[2],
[TipoPeriodo].[Tipo Periodo].&[2],
[Mercato].[Mercato].&[1],
[Aziende].[Descrizione Codice Azienda].&[100 - BASF]);
```

Comment: thanks it's giving me the result as per my requirement. But I did not understand the flow. How exactly is it working? Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: @YousufSultan hi. This is in the above calculation Y `[Tempo].[Periodo].CurrentMember` ....Tempo.periodo is in the current context (i.e. the SELECT) clause, whereas you used `[Tempo].[Anno].CurrentMember` which wasn't in context. This is the main difference. I also used your user hierarchy throughout rather than mixing user and attribute hierarchies ... I have a feeling this `[Tempo].[Anno]` might be hitting an attribute hierarchy: let me add an exploratory script so you can see.

Comment: The test query that you have given is returning the corresponding years for  EcotassaTEST